# file_name, how is it accepted if it is not defined previously in my code?

Tags: python

Here is my code, which executes well and as intended. My question is, how "file_name" doesn't throw an error even though it has not been defined earlier in the code. I confirmed that it isn't a keyword.

```
import os

def rename_files():
    file_list = os.listdir(r"C:\\Users\\Abhilash\\Documents\\Udacity\\Prank")
    print file_list
    saved_path = os.getcwd()
    print ("Current Working Directory is "+saved_path)
    os.chdir(r"C:\\Users\\Abhilash\\Documents\\Udacity\\Prank")
    for file_name in file_list:
        os.rename(file_name,file_name.translate(None, "0123456789"))

rename_files()
```

Comment: it's defined when you start using it in the `for` statement..., just like `file_list` gets defined when you assign it the return value from `os.listdir`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do define it, you assign to it here:

```
for file_name in file_list:
```

The `for` loop binds the name.

Assignments are not the only way to 'define' a name in Python. Other ways are:

- Using it as a target in a `for <name> in something:` loop, as in your sample code.
- Using a name as target in a `with contextmanager as <name>:` or `except Exception as <name>:` statement.
- Importing names; `import <name>`, `from something import <name>` or `import something as <name>` all assign to that name. `from something import *` creates a whole series of names.
- Arguments to functions; calling the function sets those names.

See the [*Naming and Binding* section](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/executionmodel.html) of the Python execution model documentation.